Every linear equation which satisfies all the solutions of a consistent system of linear equations can be written as a linear combination of the equat
Suppose we have a consistent system of linear equations. We are given a linear equation which has all the solutions of the system as roots, how does one prove that this equation can infact be written as a linear combination of the equations of the consistent system?
